# Make array keys to start from 0 again in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called `$Compare`, I used the `print_r()` function in php:

```
Array ([2] => Broccoli, raw [3] => Candies, butterscotch [4] => Celery, raw [10] => Apricots, raw)
```

I want it the keys to be in the correct order: 0,1,2,3 not 2,3,4,10!

In the end it should look like this:

```
Array ([0] => Broccoli, raw [1] => Candies, butterscotch [2] => Celery, raw [3] => Apricots, raw)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$Compare = array_values($Compare);
```